# Why does the iphone make my text big when I flip it over?

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile-safari

I have some `div`s as headers on a page and then text underneath them. When I flip the phone over onto its side the text suddenly becomes inflated even though there is no CSS to do this.

What could be doing this?

Comment: Screenshots or code would be useful here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the iPhone is held in portrait, it has a width of 320 pixels (or 640 on the iPhone 4). When it is held horizontally, its width is 480 pixels. The “zoom” effect you’re describing is MobileSafari redrawing the text for the larger width.

Answer (score 1):

I find out, that if div have enough place to large inner text, text will be bigger. But if div is inline element or just have no free space, text will not be scaled after iPhone rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the viewport using the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Hope this helps. It helped me getting a consistent mobile page.

Bob

Comment: thanks for the reply....Tried this and now it draws the text bigger and then bigger again when I flip it.... HELP someone please project deadline tomorrow!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Right i got it...

Basically even when I set the viewport sizings it still messes up. to stop this happeing I have placed the elements in a div with a fixed width of 320px.

That way the text size is in the same size div when horizontal or not..

Cheers
Pete